# MySQL Views Support in Sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, view, sequelize.js

I woululd like to use sequelize as my ORM in a web app I am building. The app will be based on NodeJS - Express for constructing and MySQL as its relational database. What I haven't found anywhere on documentaino or on the net, is how to declare in sequelize models the "Views" that exist in my MySQL Database....

Is the only way to manually construct the query SQL? Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution to creating views with sequelize code-first style? I also have the same need.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't... The only workaroung that I use right now in my code, is declaring the views like normal tables with sequelize definition. The only attention that should be given is for the primary keys. You could declare a composite key to make sure each row is unique.

Comment: Bummer. Well thanks for the response, I believe I'm doing the same thing at the moment -- creating the view through the database interface, then creating a sequelize definition for it separately, and finally not syncing that definition so sequelize doesn't try to make a table. It works, but feels odd when I'm using sync to create the other database objects. Murphy's law #2, I suppose.

Comment: Yeap, that's about it.... I believe it is a major backstep, to include composite primary key support and not support the composite foreign key... I hope they have the time to implement it sometime. It is a very wanted feature.. Anyway, the rest is very good work!

Comment: @dvlsg any attributes you specified when creating the model definition? I've specified the schema but it doesn't seem like it's getting the data from the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Node ORM2, which has support for MySQL views as well.

Try at

```
https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2
```